# Sublime sass linter says there is an error but there isn't

Tags: sass, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

## Sublime Linter

I am using the package *SublimeLinter-contrib-sass-lint* and decided to test it out on some code i know compiles. I noticed an error on the very first line seen in the picture below.

[image]

The error in the footer shows up as

> Error: Please check validity of the block starting from line #1. (Fatal), Line 1 Column 1

## Question

My `contact.scss` file compiles and runs fine so why is this error being thrown? Is this a bug in the linter or does it throw errors for things that are bad practice?

## Edit 1

I have stripped out all of the code bar the background image and the error persists.

```
.contact{
    background-image: url('../images/backgrounds/lol.jpg');
}
```

Comment: can you post complete css code of .contact so that can find error.

Comment: @IqbalPasha I have stripped it alll  out and the error persists. look at the edit. its not a problem with my code from what I can see.

Comment: error is stared from line #1 can you let me know where .contact is closed "}"

Comment: its like right there in the edit. it opens then has a background image then closes.